# reading input file in fortran

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I am looking for reading a file, like:

```
NE                32         0
IBZINT             2
NKTAB            936
XC-POT    VWN       
ITER          29
MIX     2.00000000000000E-01
TOL     1.00000000000000E-05
```

I was thinking it is `index` `intrinsic` that I am looking for, and was writing a code accordingly:

**EDIT** The code is updated,

```
   Implicit None
    integer ::i,pos
    character(50) :: name
    character(len=16),dimension(100)::key,val
    key(1)="NE"
    open(12,file="FeRh/FeRh.pot_new",status="old")
    do i=1,100
      read(12,*)name
      if (name(1:2)==key(1))then
        write(*,*)"find NE"
        write(*,*)name(1:2)
        write(*,*)name(index("NE","")+21)
      endif
    end do
    close(12)
    !write(*,*)index(key(1),"")
    End Program  readpot
```

I am expecting to have 32 in the 3rd `write` statement.
Must have gone horribly wrong some where. can you kindly help?

Comment: What are the symptoms for "horribly wrong"?  The lack of `read`s probably doesn't help, though.

Comment: You appear to be missing a `:` in the third write.  Is that meant to be `name(index("NE",""):21)`?

Answer (score 1):

When you want to read a line from the file you are using list-directed (`*` as the format) input.  This isn't what you want as there will be some limited parsing by the run-time.

That is, `read(12,*) name` on the first record will result in `"NE"` padded with lots of spaces in the variable `name` as the record will be split on the spaces.

As you want the entire line in `name`, use the format `'(A)'` in the `read`.

Once you have that line, you can then do your further parsing.  However, from what you show `index` doesn't seem to be helping, especially as you are checking against an empty substring.  You know the length of the key (using `len_trim`) so if you have a match you know the location of the first separator.

Answer (score 0):

If I wanted to read a line such as

```
NE                32         0
```

I'd write a statement such as

```
read(12,*) name, int1, int2
```

and expect my processor to set `name` to `NE`, `int1` to `32` and `int2` to `0`, if, that is, I'd declared `int1` and `int2` to be integers.

I'm puzzled that you seem to want to read a line of text and then parse it, all the while ignoring the benefits of *list-directed* input. If you do want to parse it into something other than a character variable and two integers, let us know.

Comment: I want to read all the values, NE 32 0 is just as a minimal example, later I need it to be used in the main programme. How I can parse it?

Comment: If you want to read a line which contains a short string followed by two integers, all separated by spaces, follow my suggestion.  If you need to parse the line in some other way, explain how.

Comment: the issue I think is he needs top read lines that are differently formatted depending on the keyword. Reading the whole line as a string then  conditionally (list) reading from the string is a good way to go.