# parsing output file with fortran: last occurance of a given string

Tags: parsing, fortran

connected to my [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21581647/parsing-input-file-in-fortran) post, for some more data, I need to find the last occurance of a string, and then I have to parse some more data using fortran.
the output solves a problem iteratively  and writes the data in the out file. each iteration starts with a string like:

```
 *******************************************************************************

 Next iteration

char_data_a=real_value     
char_data_b=real_value_b
```

until self consistency is achieved. So, by coding, I dont have any idea how many line to skip. I need to go to the last occurrence of "Next iteration" and start parsing it.

Kindly help.

**NB:** I know, its against the ethics of the forum to post a problem w/o a code, but in this case, I need to know how to code it.

Comment: Posting this question without any code suggests that you have been blindly following the advice you've been given previously, but not succeeded in learning, from that advice, how to start writing programs to tackle this sort of problem for yourself.  So, step 1, write down the steps you want your new routine to execute, bingo, you have a pseudo-code for your routine.  Step 2, translate the pseudo-code into Fortran.  Bang, now you have a program that we can help you finish, if necessary.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark, The problem in this case is that I can't read through the whole file, as this may be very large. so, reading line by line is not a good idea here. That's why I am looking for a way to jump to the last occurrence of that string. am I missing something from previous post? not obvious to me. kindly help/comment.

Comment: What do you mean by *very large* ?  Even a program which reads a very large file line-by-line slowly would be better than what you have right now.

Comment: By far the easiest solution to code is to read the file and figure that you have found the last occurrence when you read far enough more and don't find another.  Why not try coding that and see if the performance is acceptable?  You can either store the lines that were read past the last occurrence and need to be processed, or use Fortran backspace.  Or rewrite the program that is making this output to have more convenient output.

Comment: What about preprocessing with `grep`, `head` and `tail`?